# "such that" or "so that"

Tags: phrase-choice

Which boldfaced option is correct int he following?

> Zhang and his team reportedly concocted the revolutionary ooze by mixing neodymium magnet particles with household detergent borax and the resin polyvinyl alcohol, the first ingredient **so (that)** it can be controlled magnetically, Reuters reported. They then coated the toxic magnetic particles with silica to hypothetically make them safe for use inside the human body.

> Zhang and his team reportedly concocted the revolutionary ooze by mixing neodymium magnet particles with household detergent borax and the resin polyvinyl alcohol, the first ingredient **such that** it can be controlled magnetically, Reuters reported. They then coated the toxic magnetic particles with silica to hypothetically make them safe for use inside the human body.

Comment: Asking "which is correct" is off-topic. To make this question on-topic you'd need to add some research or context.

Answer (score 1):

It should be "so that".

"So that" denotes the purpose or the effect of something or it carries the idea ‘in order that’ while "such that" emphasizes on the manner or the way to which extent something is described. [Source](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-so-that-and-vs-such-that/amp/)

In this case the first ingredient *causes* the ooze to be magnetically controlled.

Comment: If "the first ingredient" were not in the sentence, I'd think "so that" is okay.

Comment: Your distinction itself is correct (***so*** explicitly references to ***purpose***, whereas ***such*** simply alludes to ***effect***, not *necessarily* purposeful). But in the cited context, obviously the only *reason* for adding neodymium is to enable magnetic control, so ***so that*** is perfectly valid. And in fact, since ***so that*** is far more common in such contexts, I think one could reasonably say it "should" be ***so that***. But in practice, for the *exact* context, it's just a stylistic choice - where the writer deliberately chose the more "erudite" alternative.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Is this correct then? The added sugar is so (that) the cake tastes sweet.

Comment: @Apollyon: Yes. Strictly speaking, *The added sugar is so (that) the cake tastes sweet* is "reduced" from something like ***The reason for (the existence of)** the added sugar is...,* but your version is perfectly natural in informal contexts. Note that ***that*** is (almost?) always optional after ***so*** in such constructions, but it ***must*** be included in the synonymous alternative ***in order that** [some desired outcome should be the result].*